# Using NLopt as a solver of JuMP

Tags: julia, nlopt

I'm trying to optimize a function using NLopt.

I tried to use the example in NLopt.jl but I wasn't able to fix the error.

```
using JuMP
using NLopt

m = Model(solver=NLoptSolver(algorithm=:LD_MMA))

a1 = 2
b1 = 0
a2 = -1
b2 = 1

@variable(m, x1)
@variable(m, x2 >= 0)

@NLobjective(m, Min, sqrt(x2))
@NLconstraint(m, x2 >= (a1*x1+b1)^3)
@NLconstraint(m, x2 >= (a2*x1+b2)^3)

setvalue(x1, 1.234)
setvalue(x2, 5.678)

status = solve(m)

println("got ", getobjectivevalue(m), " at ", [getvalue(x1),getvalue(x2)])
```

I don't know how to use with_optimizer.

Comment: `NLopt` was compatible with JuMP up to release 0.18. If your JuMP version is 0.19, you cannot use JuMP with `NLOpt` until `NLOpt` implements the new MathOptInterface API. See http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/v0.19.0/installation/ and https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl/issues/130

Comment: Thanks, I gave up on using JuMP and tried Optim.jl instead.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking, there is currently no solution to the problem.

Currently, JuMP uses the syntax

`model = Model(optimizer)
set_optimizer_attribute(model, "attribue", value)`

That would be the correct way to setting the "algorithm" = algorithm attribute for NLoptSolver.

However, the NLoptSolver package has not been updated to allow for loading the optimizer without the algorithm attribute, and so it is currently unable to use JuMP.

[Source](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/dev/solvers/#JuMP.set_optimizer_attributes)